# docker protractor - Server terminated early with status 127

Tags: docker, protractor

I have a working example on my windows 10 machine. When I port this over to linux, via a container using: node:8, I get error 127.

I am not familiar enough with linux or essential requirements, ie does it need a java installation, or other?

#### package.json

```js
{
  "name": "test1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver-update-chrome": "webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=78.0.3904.105",
    "test-protractor": "protractor protractor.conf.js --disableChecks"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "cucumber": "^6.0.5",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^6.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

#### protractor.conf

```js
const protractor = require('protractor');

// console.log('browser = ', browser);
exports.config = {
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  getPageTimeout: 60000,
  allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
  specs: ['features/*.feature'],
  baseURL: 'http://www.google.com/',
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: [
      './features/step_definitions/stepDefinitions.js'
    ],
    tags: false,
    profile: false,
    'no-source': true
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);

  },
  capabilities: {
    browserName: "chrome",
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        '--allow-insecure-localhost',
        '--headless',
        '--disaple-gpu',
        '--window-size=1920,1080',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
      ],
      prefs: {
        download: {
          prompt_for_download: false,
          extensions_to_open: ''
        },
        profile: {
          default_content_settings: {
            popups: 0
          }
        },
        directory_upgrade: true
      },
      useAutomationExtension: false
    }
  },
  // connec direct to webdriver, instead of local selenium server!
  directConnect: true,
  ignoreUncaughtException: true,
  onComplete: () => {
    // Reporter.createHtmlReport();
  }
}
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8


# Create and define the node_modules's cache directory.
RUN mkdir /usr/src/cache
WORKDIR /usr/src/cache

COPY . .
RUN npm install

# run update to get all drivers
RUN npm run webdriver-update

## update to specific chrome version - 78.0.3904.105
RUN npm run webdriver-update-chrome

# overwrite any remaining references to wrong chromedriver...
RUN sed -i -e 's/chromedriver[^"]*/chromedriver_78.0.3904.105/g' node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/update-config.json

# run tests
RUN npm run test-protractor
```

The above sed command simple ensures that update-config.json is using the above selected chrome version.

#### update-config.json

eg:

```
  "node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_78.0.3904.105.exe"
```

#### Error:

> Server terminated early with status 127

Comment: what is the full error stack?

Comment: `.exe` can't work on linux.  `chromedriver_78.0.3904.105.exe` only work on windows.  But `npm run webdriver-update` and `npm run webdriver-update-chrome`  should install linux chrome driver for you. Please update the files under `node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium` in your question, to help us to see correct chrome driver installed or not.

Comment: sorry, I added the .exe as example, but thats not whats in the update-config.json. The sed command above merely replaces the version number, and doesnt touch the file extension, so it is retained as the original. ie in linux no ext and in windows keeps the ext.

Comment: I've shown below without using specific chromdriver update. This time just showing version chromedriver version 8. See below:

Answer (score 0):

## full stack error below:

```
 ---> Running in f001e88bdac0
Removing intermediate container f001e88bdac0
 ---> 7016f93ad697
Step 9/13 : RUN sed -i -e 's/chromedriver[^"]*/chromedriver_78.0.3904.105/g' node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/update-config.json
 ---> Running in 85e4466ff4d5
Removing intermediate container 85e4466ff4d5
 ---> 385d8dca6be9
Step 10/13 : RUN npm run test-protractor
 ---> Running in 8304e6de67c9

> test1@1.0.0 test-protractor /usr/src/cache
> protractor protractor.conf.js --disableChecks

[22:53:19] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[22:53:19] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[22:53:19] E/launcher - Server terminated early with status 127
[22:53:19] E/launcher - Error: Server terminated early with status 127
    at earlyTermination.catch.e (/usr/src/cache/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:252:52)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/usr/src/cache/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/usr/src/cache/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/usr/src/cache/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/src/cache/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/src/cache/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /usr/src/cache/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/usr/src/cache/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[22:53:19] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remove my references to specific chrome version, and just run webdriver-manager update, as follows:

#### dockerfile

```
FROM node:8


# Create and define the node_modules's cache directory.
RUN mkdir /usr/src/cache
WORKDIR /usr/src/cache

COPY . .
RUN npm install

# run update to get all drivers
RUN npm run webdriver-update

# run tests
RUN npm run test-protractor
```

#### This is my error

```
> webdriver-manager update

[05:14:17] I/file_manager - creating folder /usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium
[05:14:17] I/config_source - curl -o/usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/standalone-response.xml https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
[05:14:17] I/config_source - curl -o/usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
[05:14:17] I/config_source - curl -o/usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/gecko-response.json https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
[05:14:18] I/downloader - curl -o/usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.141/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
[05:14:18] I/downloader - curl -o/usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_80.0.3987.16.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/80.0.3987.16/chromedriver_linux64.zip
[05:14:21] I/downloader - curl -o/usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.26.0.tar.gz https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.26.0/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz
[05:14:23] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_80.0.3987.16.zip
[05:14:23] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_80.0.3987.16 [05:14:29] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.26.0.tar.gz
[05:14:29] I/update - geckodriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.26.0
Removing intermediate container 7a4b12efa5b4
 ---> 8d02b754b748
Step 7/9 : RUN npm run test-protractor
 ---> Running in fe8c7c731d48

> test1@1.0.0 test-protractor /usr/src/cache
> protractor protractor.conf.js --disableChecks

[05:14:31] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[05:14:31] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[05:14:31] W/launcher - Ignoring uncaught error Error: Server terminated early with status 127
[05:14:32] E/launcher - BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 100
npm ERR! test1@1.0.0 test-protractor: `protractor protractor.conf.js --disableChecks`
npm ERR! Exit status 100
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test1@1.0.0 test-protractor script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-02-07T05_14_32_065Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run test-protractor' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

#### protractor.conf

I noticed a mistake in my config, and corrected 'ignoreUncaughtExceptions' with the s on the end =

```
exports.config = {
...
  ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,
```

Though it doesn't resolve the problem. I Still get the same problem.

#### update-config.json

```js
{
  "chrome": {
    "last": "/usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_80.0.3987.16",
    "all": [
      "/usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_80.0.3987.16"
    ]
  },
  "standalone": {
    "last": "/usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar",
    "all": [
      "/usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar"
    ]
  },
  "gecko": {
    "last": "/usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.26.0",
    "all": [
      "/usr/src/cache/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.26.0"
    ]
  }
}
```